# Convert User Conversation of Dialogflow in text/excel sheet

Tags: excel, api, dialogflow-es

I want to convert user conversations from Dialogflow to txt file or  excel sheet. Well, I can check the history of conversation from history tab shown in dialogflow console. And I want to store this to a excel sheet.

I have also checked the api's of Dialogflow and didn't found anything that can solve my Problem.

Answer (score 0):

As explained in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49683853/10801700), currently there is not direct way to store the Dialogflow chat history. What can be done is to retrieve messages with [fulfillments](https://dialogflow.com/docs/fulfillment).

[Check this GitHub repository](https://github.com/Alp78/dialogflow-extract) for the logic to retrieve messages. The API fields  `queryText` and `fulfillmentText` are the ones you want.